# How to extend the "less" command behavior?

Tags: unix, binary

In normal cases, I suppose everyone only uses the "less" command to read the content of plain text files.

But on Gentoo, it seems that the less command line is a little more powerful than the one I use on other Linux distributions, or Cygwin, Mac OS X... the less command on Gentoo is able to list the content of compressed archive files, the ELF header and other information of executable files, and maybe more...
I can't remember on what platform it was, but I think it is also possible to read PDF files with some versions of "less" (or maybe was it just a dream?).

So I wonder if there is a way to easily make extensions for the less command, for example to make it able to read (display in a nice way) some format of binary files. I searched for information about this on Google, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [`lesspipe.sh`](http://www-zeuthen.desy.de/%7Efriebel/unix/lesspipe.html)?

Actually, `lesspipe.sh` only processes file or url before piping to less. BTW, I'm not using this, but I often type `ps2ascii some.pdf | less` to read pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/less-is-more-the-hidden-treasure-of-less-command.html) page and [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/linux-less-command-open-view-different-files-less-is-more/) page, less already has PDF support, at least in that version

I tried less'ing a couple different PDF files, at it looks like some are graphics based and some are text based.  I was able to read the text based ones, but not so much the graphics ones as they were all commands an not so much text.

Answer (score 0):

Just did a "man less" on my Mac. less can work with input preprocessors. The man page had an example of setting up a preprocessor shell script to work with archives. The preprocessor recognizes the extension and fed the uncompressed file into less. You specify the preprocessor script with environment variables LESSOPEN and LESSCLOSE.

Maybe your full-featured system had some scripts specified by LESSOPEN. Look in your environment for LESSOPEN.

Cool, I learned something new looking for an answer.

Note: I usually use "readelf -h" to dump ELF headers. Very useful when I am cross-compiling and need to verify the library format.

Answer (score 0):

Try "man lessfile" and "man lesspipe" for documentation on this behaviour.

On Ubuntu, less processes PDFs into plain text by default. (I actually find this annoying since when I type "less something.pdf" it's usually because I want to look at the raw PDF. Easily worked around with "less < something.pdf" for the single-file case, though.)

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this, as I can see many binary files with `less`, but once in a while, a binary type just isn't supported and adding support would be great...

First of all, I'd like to report that this is actually documented:

```
man lesspipe
```

The best is for you to create a script or even a binary using a language such as C or C++ and place that executable code in:

```
~/.lessfilter
```

The default `lesspipe` script will run that executable if it exists and is executable (`x` permission bit set). If you output results and then exit successfully (`exit 0`), then that output will be shown. If you do not recognize the input file, you can simply exit with an error (`exit 1`).

Here is an example to display an ELF file *headers* (what I like to see when I check such a file):

```
#!/bin/bash -e
# Detect file type using `file ...` instead of extension
MIME=`file --brief --mime-type "$1"`
case "${MIME}" in
"application/x-sharedlib")
    objdump -x $1
    exit 0
    ;;
esac
exit 1
```

You can very easily extend that script adding new cases and running whatever command(s) you want to generate the output you prefer.

In this way, you can even hijack some of the already implemented functions from the default script.

**Note:** There is actually a github project named [`lesspipe`](https://github.com/wofr06/lesspipe) which has a much better version of that file than the currently supported Debian package.

---

#### Steps to Find the Correct Answer

I think that looking at the `/usr/bin/lesspipe` is close to the correct answer. However, it did seem to imply that you would have to update that script and doing so will be overwritten each time the corresponding package is updated.

Looking at the script, though, it tells us that we can have your own extension.

First of all, the `$LESSOPEN` variable is important. This is what defines the location of the `lesspipe` script. It's found under `/usr/bin` on Ubuntu, it could be somewhere else on a different Unix system.

So we first want to look at the location of the script:

```
echo $LESSOPEN
```

In my case, I see this:

```
| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
```

Which says, pipe the output of the `lesspipe` script. This is expected to be a temporary filename that `lesspipe` just created. If no filename is output, then the input file is directly shown by less.

Now, for us to extend the `lesspipe` script to support new binary file types, one looks at the script and notices this section:

```
            if [ -x ~/.lessfilter ]; then
                    ~/.lessfilter "$1"
                    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                            if [ $BASENAME = $LESSFILE ]; then
                                    if [ -s $TMPFILE ]; then
                                            echo $TMPFILE
                                    else
                                            rm -f $TMPFILE
                                    fi
                            fi
                            exit 0
                    fi
            fi
```

which tells us that we can have our very own script under `~/.lessfilter`.

This is a shell script or even an ELF binary. Anything that can be executed, really, and will be able to exit with 0 if it generated some valid output.

Notice that the code goes further and echoes `$TMPFILE` in that event. I have no idea why it does that since `$TMPFILE` is generally empty. All we have to do in our script (and you can see the same below in the `lesspipe` script), is to write anything we want to standard output (file descriptor 1) and exit with 0. The rest works as expected and it makes your script pretty simple (compared to the `lesspipe` script which handles many other cases, such as `-` as input, that you can ignore on your end).

Answer (score -1):

less is open, if you don't like the one you have, just grab a more up to date one.